# ajax.done function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function and I want it to execute some code when it's done. I have got this but it doesn't work. The alert doesn't pop up.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://www.sinansamet.nl/chatdistract/ajax/getRooms.php",
    success: function(html) {
              $("#"+id+" ul").append(html);
              $("#"+id+" ul").listview("refresh");
            }
    }).done(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
```

Comment: dont use success and done. replace one or the other

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Not sure but should be the last stable version. It worked but I implied the .done() in the wrong function. Sorry for my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 3):

As @karthikr said in his comment, it makes little sense to use both `success:` and `.done()`, since they do the same job. But on a successful connect, they should both run. That said....

Your problem might be because you're accessing a different domain, which never resolves and thus never triggers `.done()`.

Try changing `.done()` to `.always()`, which resolves whether there's a success or failure to connect.

Comment: Im sorry the function worked I just implied the .done() in the wrong function... Stupid mistake. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think an appropriate question is, are you getting an error?  I notice that you are using the full domain for your request, which requires [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in modern browsers, and won't work in IE < 10 (jQuery doesn't use the IE specific cross-domain request object, which iirc requires CORS as well).

The "done" method (which was implemented with the promises refactor around jQuery 1.5.x) doesn't fire when an error occurs.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Try the following snippet, and look at your JS console in the browser.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://www.sinansamet.nl/chatdistract/ajax/getRooms.php",
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ //same as .success (depricated as of 1.8)
    console.log("done");
    console.dir(arguments);
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ //replaces .error
    console.log("error");
    console.dir(arguments);
  })
  .always(function(/*data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown*/){ //replaces .complete
    console.log("always");
    console.dir(arguments);
  })
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing cross-domain ajax Call? If you're not in the same domain as www.sinansamet.nl, the Ajax call will fail.

Either let the server do the cross-domain call or use a crossdomain.xml